# I want to create wet trails from an image sequence. Is it possible to use an image sequence as a brush? Or are there other alternatives?

Tags: texturing, materials, dynamic-paint

I created an image sequence in After Effects to use as a bump map for a texture.

I also want to use that image sequence as a 'paint brush' so that I can get wet 2d streaks that are left behind and evaporate / fade out.

I could use AE to make these trails but I think wet maps would be more realistic and much easier on processing compared to the method I'd use in AE.

Currently the only idea I have would only potentially work with flat surface. The idea would be to use the AE image sequence as a bump map on a plane and set it close to the canvas object. Then set the plane with the bump map as a brush and play and export a wet map as usual. I'm not sure, however, if this would work at all.

Is there any better / other way to do this in Blender?

Comment: you can use dynamic paint for that.

Comment: How? How do I use an image sequence as a brush?